# How to make service not require superuser password entry?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, cron

I am doing the command `service cron start` in the shell which requires a superuser password entry. I am the root user on this (OracleVB running Ubuntu).

Is there a way to add this command to an approved user task where I can just type `service cron start` and not be prompted for a password?

Comment: Is there any reason to start `cron` manually? Usually it runs at all times

Comment: I am running a django_crontab cron service and I guess I was running the command before starting the server each time just to ensure cron is running. 

If it is always in the background I will just assume it to be on from this point forward. Thanks

Comment: You can check with `sudo systemctl status cron` and enable a service  to start at boot with `sudo systemctl enable  --now cron`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks again for your quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting and stopping system services should only be possible for the root user.

You might want to enable your service to start at boot with `systemctl enable --now yourservice` instead.

You can always use `systemctl status yourservice` to check if it is currently running.